# why Getting error on uploading the file with Webp-ffi gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webp

Unsupported color conversion request
*** WebP::EncoderError Exception: Cannot read input picture file
got this error on certain jpg file. while converting into jpg again from google does the job but why is this?

'''webp_path = "#{filename.ext}.webp"

```
  # Encode (convert) image to webp format with passed options
  WebP.encode(path, webp_path, options)

  # HACK: Changing of this two instance variables is the only way 
  #   I found to make CarrierWave save new file that was created 
  #   by encoding original image.
  @filename = webp_path.split('/').pop

  @file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(
    tempfile: webp_path,
    filename: webp_path,
    content_type: 'image/webp'
  )'''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use successfully, obviously need MiniMagick installed on the dev computer and server:

```
class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/story/#{model.created_at.strftime('%Y').to_s.underscore}/#{model.created_at.strftime('%m').to_s.underscore}/#{model.created_at.strftime('%d').to_s.underscore}"
  end

  def default_url(*args)
    "/fallback.webp"
  end

  process :resize_to_fill => [1200, 677]
  process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80 }]

  version :preview do
    process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80, resize_w: 470, resize_h: 265 }]
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png webp)
  end

  private

  def convert_to_webp(options = {})
    # Build path for new file
    webp_path = "#{path}.webp"

    # Encode (convert) image to webp format with passed options
    WebP.encode(path, webp_path, options)

    # HACK: Changing of this two instance variables is the only way 
    #   I found to make CarrierWave save new file that was created 
    #   by encoding original image.
    @filename = webp_path.split('/').pop.split('.').first + '.webp'

    @file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(
      tempfile: webp_path,
      filename: webp_path,
      content_type: 'image/webp'
    )
  end
end
```